# ExtJs 6.X; How do you change the color of a gauge chart using a value

Tags: extjs, charts, gauge

With previous versions of ExtJS you could change the background color of the gauge using the following:

```
renderer: function (sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
            if (attr.fill == this.colorSet[1]) return Ext.apply(attr, { fill: attr.fill });
            var value = record.get("SLA"),
                color;
            if (value >= 95) {
                color = "#0000ff";
            } else if (value < 85) {
                color = "#00ff00";
            } else {
                color = "#ff0000";
            }
            return Ext.apply(attr, { fill: color });
        }
```

Does anyone know the new way to do this with the 6.X framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 6.x, the parameters passed to the `renderer` function are `sprite, config, rendererData, index`.  These are described in the [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.chart.series.Gauge.html#cfg-renderer).  The renderer could be written as:

```
   renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
        var value = rendererData.value;
        var color;
        if (value >= 95) {
            color = "#0000ff";
        } else if (value < 85) {
            color = "#00ff00";
        } else {
            color = "#ff0000";
        }
        return {
            fill: color
        };

    }
```